# Show that $_$ is in Hilbert space $H$ and that the series converges in H

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let H be the Hilbert space $L_2([-1,1])$ with the standard inner product:
$$\langle f|g \rangle=\int_{-1}^1 \bar{f}(x)g(x)dx$$ and define the functions, $f_n$, $n=0,1,2,3,...,$ on $[-1,1]$ by
$$f_n(x)=x^n$$

We have to show that the functions $f_n$ belong to $H$ and that for $|A|<1$ the series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a^nf_n$ converges in H with sum function f given by:
$$f(x)=\frac{ax}{1-ax}, x \in[-1,1]$$

I'm not quite sure how to show that? It seems there is not a recipe how to show and find the sum function. But maybe I can use some inequality or something to get a nicer expression or some tricks? Hope anyone can help me?

Comment: Didn't you already asked this yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $f_n \in H$ you just need to prove that $\int_{-1}^1 (x^n)^2 dx < \infty$ for all $n$ (straightforward computation).

For the second question, you must note that you have a geometric progression. Each term is the previous one times $\alpha x$, where $-1<\alpha x < 1$. Hence the series converges to the formula you have written. Remember that in general the sum of a geometric series that grows by a factor of $|\beta|<1$ converges, and it converges to $\frac{c}{1-\beta}$, where $c$ is the first term of the sequence.

Finally, to show that also $f \in H$, you must check that $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)^2 dx < \infty$.